# MySQL Optimization Problem

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I'm having problems with a query optimization. The following query takes more than 30 seconds to get the expected result.

```
SELECT tbl_history.buffet_q_rating, tbl_history.cod_stock, tbl_history.bqqq_change_month, stocks.ticker, countries.country, stocks.company
FROM tbl_history
INNER JOIN stocks ON tbl_history.cod_stock = stocks.cod_stock
INNER JOIN exchange ON stocks.cod_exchange = exchange.cod_exchange
INNER JOIN countries ON exchange.cod_country = countries.cod_country
WHERE exchange.cod_country =125
AND DATE = '2011-07-25'
AND bqqq_change_month IS NOT NULL 
AND buffet_q_rating IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY bqqq_change_month DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_history` (
`cod_stock` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`price` decimal(11,3) DEFAULT NULL,
`buffet_q_rating` decimal(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`bqqq_change_day` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`bqqq_change_month` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
(...)
PRIMARY KEY (`cod_stock`,`date`),
KEY `cod_stock` (`cod_stock`),
KEY `buf_rating` (`buffet_q_rating`),
KEY `data` (`date`),
KEY `bqqq_change_month` (`bqqq_change_month`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stocks` (
`cod_stock` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cod_exchange` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cod_stock`),
KEY `exchangestocks` (`cod_exchange`),
KEY `codstock` (`cod_stock`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exchange` (
`cod_exchange` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`exchange` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`cod_country` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cod_exchange`),
KEY `countriesexchange` (`cod_country`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
`cod_country` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`country` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`initial_amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cod_country`),
KEY `codcountry` (`cod_country`),
KEY `country` (`country`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

The first table have more than 20 million rows, the second have 40k and the others have  just a few rows (maybe 100).

Them problem seems to be the "order by" but I have no idea how to optimize it.
I already tried some things searching on google/stackoverflow but I was unable to get good results
Can someone give me some advice?

**EDIT:** 
Forgot the EXPLAIN result:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  countries   const   PRIMARY,codcountry  PRIMARY 4   const   1   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  exchange    ref PRIMARY,countriesexchange   countriesexchange   5   const   15  Using where
1   SIMPLE  stocks  ref PRIMARY,exchangestocks,codstock exchangestocks  5   databaseName.exchange.cod_exchange  661 Using where
1   SIMPLE  tbl_history eq_ref  PRIMARY,cod_stock,buf_rating,data,bqqq_change_mont...   PRIMARY 12  v.stocks.cod_stock,const    1   Using where
```

---

**UPDATE**

this is the new EXPLAIN I got:

```
id select_type table type   possible_keys                       key        key_len ref   rows Extra |
1  SIMPLE tbl_history range monthstats                          monthstats      14 NULL  80053 Using where; Using index |
1  SIMPLE countries   ref   country                             country          4 const     1 Using index |
1  SIMPLE exchange    ref   PRIMARY,cod_country,countryexchange countryexchange  5 cons‌​t     5 Using where; Using index |
1  SIMPLE stocks      ref   info4stats                          info4stats       9 databaseName.exchange.cod_exchange,d‌​atabaseName.stock_...                    1 Using where; Using index |
```

Comment: Can you paste the explain result of this query? That will give you some insights on how mysql is using the indexes etc.

Comment: You could try specifying the `bqqq_change_month` index as `DESC` though I can't tell for sure if this is supported correctly yet

Comment: I would surely add a compound index on table `stocks` on `(cod_exchange,cod_stock)`

Comment: And i would try on table `history` a compound index on `(bqqq_change_month, buffet_q_rating, date, cod_stock)`

Comment: @ypercube I tried your suggestions and the first one helped. The second, I found a better order for the compound, at least gives me better execution time with (date,cod_stock,bqqq_change_month,buffet_q_rating) maybe its because I have about 800 different dates and bqqq_change_month its around 20 million different rows

Comment: @Rafael: Yes, that makes sense. Can you post the EXPLAIN plan, after the addition of those indices?

Comment: Another thing: How many rows satisfy the condition `WHERE exchange.cod_country =125 AND DATE = '2011-07-25' AND bqqq_change_month IS NOT NULL AND buffet_q_rating IS NOT NULL` and how many the `WHERE exchange.cod_country =125 AND DATE = '2011-07-25'` ?

Comment: With `WHERE exchange.cod_country =125 AND DATE = '2011-07-25' AND bqqq_change_month IS NOT NULL AND buffet_q_rating IS NOT NULL` I got 4,101 rows.
With `WHERE exchange.cod_country =125 AND DATE = '2011-07-25` got 5,725

Now I am using different indexes and I can get results in 0.1s. 

The indexes are:

exchange: (cod_country,cod_exchange)
stocks: (cod_exchange,cod_stock,country,ticker)
tbl_history: (date,bqqq_change_month,buffet_q_rating,cod_stock)

I tried many different indexes and this are the only that dont give me the "using temporary, using file sort"

Comment: @ypercube this is the new EXPLAIN I got:
    id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra |
    1 SIMPLE tbl_history range monthstats monthstats 14 NULL 80053 Using where; Using index |
    1 SIMPLE countries ref country country 4 const 1 Using index |
    1 SIMPLE exchange ref PRIMARY,cod_country,countryexchange countryexchange 5 const 5 Using where; Using index |
    1 SIMPLE stocks ref info4stats info4stats 9 databaseName.exchange.cod_exchange,databaseName.stock_... 1 Using where; Using index |

Comment: @Rafael: How much time does it take now?

Comment: 0.15 (average) seconds. Its perfect, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to preemptively start with the Country records for 125 and work in reverse.  By using a Straight_join will force the order of your query as entered...

I would also have an index on your Tbl_History table by the COD_Stock and DATE( `date` ).  So the query will properly and efficiently match the join condition on the pre-qualified date portion of the date/time field.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      th.buffet_q_rating, 
      th.cod_stock, 
      th.bqqq_change_month, 
      stocks.ticker, 
      c.country, 
      s.company
   FROM 
      Exchange e
         join Countries c
            on e.Cod_Country = c.Cod_Country
         join Stocks s
            on e.cod_exchange = s.cod_exchange
            join tbl_history th
               on s.cod_stock = th.cod_stock
              AND th.`Date` = '2011-07-25'
              AND th.bqqq_change_month IS NOT NULL 
              AND th.buffet_q_rating IS NOT NULL 
   WHERE
      e.Cod_Country = 125
   ORDER BY 
      th.bqqq_change_month DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

Comment: As another user suggested I created some compound indexes and now I have some good results. I can get the results in 0.2 (average) seconds with the query I wrote.
With yours I get almost the same result and the only difference in EXAMPLE its the order, it starts in exchange table and coutries after. With this query I keep getting the "using temporary, using file sort" and I dont know how to remove it. Any ideia how?
I use this indexes:
tbl_history: (cod_user,date,buffet_q_rating,bqqq_change_month)
stocks: (cod_exchange,cod_stock,company,ticker)
exchange: (cod_country,cod_exchange)

Comment: @Rafael, I would need to see the "EXPLAIN" of my query to be sure, but you are probably getting a file sort at the join to the tbl_History because of an index not matching the criteria... I would have an index on tbl_History on the COD_STOCK, and DATE(`date`).

Comment: This is the EXPLAIN (not "example" as I wrote last time :)):
    `1 SIMPLE e ref PRIMARY,countriesexchange countriesexchange 5 const 5 Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f...
    1 SIMPLE c ref country country 4 const 1 Using index
    1 SIMPLE s ref PRIMARY,info4stats info4stats 5 databaseName.e.cod_exchange 697 Using where; Using index
    1 SIMPLE th ref monthstats monthstats 12 databaseName.s.cod_stock,const 1 Using where; Using index`

You are saying I need a compound index on (cod_stock,DATE(date))? I cant do that in mysql

Comment: Even without the DATE( `date` ), even a compound index with COD_STOCK, `date` should be better

Comment: @Rafael: DRapp is right. (i missed that `tbl_history.date` is of `datetime` datatype). If you only store dates there and not times, change it into `date` type. If you have times too, your query should be `AND DATE >= '2011-07-25' AND DATE < '2011-07-26'` and the index as DRapp's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the result, why do you do it after you join all the table?
Try to reduce the size of those big tables first (LIMIT or WHERE them) before joining them with other tables.

But you have to be sure that your original query and your modified query means the same.

**Update (Sample) :**

```
select
    tbl_user.user_id,
    tbl_group.group_name
from
    tbl_grp_user
inner join
(
    select
        tbl_user.user_id,
        tbl_user.user_name
    from
        tbl_user
    limit
        5
) as tbl_user
on
    tbl_user.user_id = tbl_grp_user.user_id
inner join
(
    select
        group_id,
        group_name
    from
        tbl_group
    where
        tbl_group.group_id > 5
) as tbl_group
on
    tbl_group.group_id = tbl_grp_user.group_id
```

Hopefully, query above will give you a hint

Comment: I am not sure if I understood, can you make an example how to limit before getting the cod_stock needed to get the results from tbl_history?